# How to snapshot a local Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I have an old laptop with an external HDD as a home server.
The server runs Ubuntu 22.04. It is my DNS server (pi-hole), file server (smb), a web server for local sites, a bunch of python scripts on corn, and much more.

I have an additional identical laptop and external HDD. I would like to backup my entire server: my files, but also configs, cronjobs, python libraries, and stored web credentials. In short, a way to recover from a dead server.

From reading online, I think the tool I'm looking for is rsync, but I'm not sure. what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Would a simple "dd" copy of the entire hard drive work?
¶ As for rsync, each night on my own system I run it with `--archive --one-file-system  --delete  --backup --quiet` on /home and /etc., but that's not for disaster recovery, but to provide historical backups (e.g. what did this file look like 2 weeks ago?).

Comment: What would the procedure be? Pull out the HDD from my backup laptop and dd from my working server to the backup hdd?

Comment: It can be done over the network. [How to Clone Linux disk partition over network using dd](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-clone-linux-disk-partition-over-network-using-dd/) is one example, but you should also read a few others to be sure you understand what you're doing.